# Are there any exceptions to the power rule?

Tags: calculus

I solved for the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{e-2x}$ and ended up with $f'(x)= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{e-2x}}$ which I believe is correct.

Where I'm confused is when I apply the power rule it doesn't seem to work. The derivative of $x^n$ should be $nx^{n-1}$. When I do $\frac{1}{2}*\sqrt{e-2x}^{-1/2}$, I end up with $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e-2x}}$ which does not seem to equal  $f'(x)= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{e-2x}}$.

Are there any exceptions to this power rule or did I mess up in any calculations?

Comment: you are missing the chain rule for $e-2x$

Comment: You forgot the Chain Rule, the Power Rule is $\frac{d}{dx}u^{n} = u'nu^{n-1}$

Comment: You need to notice that you have $-2x$ rather than $x$ and apply also the chain rule.

Comment: If it was $x$ instead of $e-2x$ it would have worked. You need to multiply with $(e-2x)’=-2$.

Comment: Ok thanks! I haven't learned the chain rule yet, but I now know why this doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FormerMath points out, you missed the chain rule.
\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{e-2x} \\
=& \frac12 (e-2x)^{-1/2} \frac{d}{dx} (e - 2x) \tag{It's '()' instead of square root} \\
=& \frac12 (e-2x)^{-1/2} (-2) \\
=& -\frac{1}{\sqrt{e-2x}}
\end{align}